# WPF DataGrid make new row TabStop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid with CanUserAddRows="True". My table has multiple columns; the user can edit the cells and jump to the next one by pressing Tab. When you are at the last column, Tab will take you to the next row.

However, if you are editing a New Row, when you Tab at the last column, the focus will jump to the next control in the windows BEFORE the new row is created.

What I need to happen is the focus to jump to the new created row in the DataGrid. I honestly have no idea where to begin attacking this problem.

EDIT: I should clarify that the first column of the new row is the one that should get the focus (Imagine someone filling the grid just with the keyboard, using tab).

Comment: So you basically want TAB to behave as ENTER?

Comment: Yes, if that's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event for the `DataGrid` to intercept the `TAB` keypress and programmatically press the `ENTER` key:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ... PreviewKeyDown="dg_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

---

```
private void dg_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        var key = Key.Enter;
        var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
        var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;

        dg.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(dg), 0, key)
        {
            RoutedEvent = routedEvent
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a clever idea, but it's not quite doing it the way it should. I made some modifications to improve it, but overall, when the Enter KeyDown event is sent, the new row is indeed selected, but on the column right below where the original Tab occurred. What should happen is the first column of the new row should be selected.

I think this is a good overall solution for the problem, with some twinking I can make it work, thanks.

Comment: "What should happen...". No. This is not how ENTER behaves.

Comment: Well, then ENTER is not what it's needed.

Comment: What about it ?

Comment: I was referring to your answer to my question of "So you basically want TAB to behave as ENTER?".

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying that I didn't know ENTER jumped right to the column below. With this new information, I'm confirming ENTER is not what it's needed, but very close. I should add that as an edit to the question hmm....